# Finding an answer to a singular matrix equation if it exists in SymPy

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, sympy

Suppose we have the matrix equation `A*x = b` where `A` is square but singular. Then in general the equation either has no solutions or infinitely many solutions. If it does have solutions, I'd like to find their form *symbolically* in terms of free variables using SymPy.

I know if we can find one specific solution `x`, then by adding vectors from the nullspace of `A` onto `x` we may find the rest, so the problem is reduced to finding just one solution. In Mathematica the function `LinearSolve` will give you such a solution, but unfortunately in SymPy all of the solvers seem to require that A be non-singular.

Does anyone know how I might find such a solution (*symbolically*) using SymPy? I've been looking into rolling my own algorithm to do this, possibly by using `A.rref()` to put `A` into reduced row echelon format first, but I'm not confident enough in my linear algebra to know if this would work stably. Another possibility might be calculating the pseudoinverse, but the function `pinv()` complains about singular matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone comes across this question, the answer is to use the `linsolve` function in the latest versions of SymPy, which has this capability.